# BETA release user survey

Tags: surveys, beta

We are doing a limited BETA release of our application and have been asked to create a online survey for the users to complete at the end.

I am not a fan of the survey approach to gathering information. I have found it difficult to get useful information out of it.

Does anyone have any guidelines or resources that give examples of questions that have been shown to give useful feedback.

I imagine the sort of feedback they are wanting is around "does the app meet your needs" etc.

Comment: Please don't ask your users to rate anything on a scale of 1 to 5.

Comment: `"does the app meet your needs?"` if you're asking that while the program is in beta, there may be a larger issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The questions that are useful for one application aren't necessarily useful for another.

Use the survey to **validate points that you are most uncertain about** and which are most critical to the success of your application.  Only you can know what those are, so you will have to come up with them.

Some advice though is that the longer you make it, the more information you will get, but from fewer people.  Make it shorter and yo will get a higher response rather but not as much information from each response.  The choice of which matters most is once again an "it depends" answer.  You need to weigh up which you think will be more useful.

Otherwise standard [survey methodology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Survey_methodology) applies.

Comment: Thanks John. This is a very limited BETA so to make sure we get enough replies to make it worthwhile I will be keeping the survey pretty short.

Comment: I agree with JohnGB. You have some theories or assumptions about your users and about their problems. Use the survey to validate those theories. Because of your theories are wrong, then your implementation is probably wrong.